# React&TypeScript: What is the type of style sheet object?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

for an object in following format, how to specify the type?

```js
    style = {
        height: '200px',
        width: '150px',
        padding: '0',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        WebkitFilter: 'drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px #666)',
        filter: 'drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px #666)',
    }
```

Comment: `React.CSSProperties`

Comment: it's an object so you could probably use a Record type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the type of any prop of any component like this:

```
type Style = React.ComponentProps<'div'>['style']
```